# Docker and uPnP

Tags: docker, upnp

I must be missing something, I try to start a minidlna server within a docker image. I manage to get access to the web interface from another host in the same network, I can do some "nc -u" commands on the UDP port and I see some reactions in the minidlna logs but from my box or my tablet, I do not see the minidlna server.

I started a minidlna server from the host and this one is visible from other devices.

What am I missing ? Is there some kind of port redirections to do to make it works or maybe some specific ports to minidlna I should bind to the host ? I did not found any clue yet :/

Thanks for your help

Comment: StackOverflow is a programming site.  Questions about configuring existing software packages are off-topic.  If you want to capture an answer to your question for future users, [superuser](http://superuser.com) would be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

So ... solved ... after fixing locales :/ I do not know why but straight after setting the same locale on the container as it is on the host, I was able to discover it from my tablet.

So thanks anyway maybe it could help someone else ;)